# Necessary and sufficient conditions for a Boolean function $f$ in $n$ variables to satisfy $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=f(x_n,...,x_2,x_1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, logic, boolean-algebra

What are necessary and sufficient conditions for a Boolean function $f$ in $n$ variables to satisfy $$f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=f(x_n,...,x_2,x_1)?$$

Functions like this may be useful in cryptographic algorithms, so I need a way to search for them.

Comment: You've already stated the necessary and sufficient condition.  I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for, beyond that.  You have not given any restrictions on what kinds of conditions are or aren't acceptable, so I don't think the question is well-posed enough to be answerable.

Comment: Conditions on the algebraic normal form or Hamming weight would be useful

Comment: Please don't put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, please [edit] the post.  Please define what you mean by a condition on the Hamming weight (weight of what?).  It would also help to give some idea of what you are imagining for conditions on the ANF.

Comment: I agree with D.W.'s comment. As a suggestion, think of the case where $n=2$ (for $n=1$, it's trivial); if $n=2$, then using infix notation this is what is called a commutative operation (if $f$ goes from a Boolean algebra to itself). What would you say are the conditions for an operation to be commutative?